# Delete all of the same relationship type between two node but still keep one of them

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have many relationships(same type) between 2 node.
Now I want to delete all of them but still keep a relationship.

Comment: sorry, I changed questrion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
MATCH (a:Node {id:1})-[r:rel]->(b:Node {id:2})
WITH collect(r) as rels
FOREACH (rel in rels[1..] | 
    DELETE rel
)
```

This query iterate over matched relationships from the second to end deleting them.

As an alternative if you do not want iterate over the relationships you can use the [APOC procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) `apoc.create.relationship`. This way you will delete all current relationships and create a new one based on the type of excluded relationships.

```
MATCH (a)-[r:rel]->(b)
DELETE r
WITH distinct a, b, type(r) as type
CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, type, {}, b) YIELD rel
RETURN rel
```